# Can I edit wsl.conf for vm which fails to boot?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed Fedora38 on Windows10 following https://www.linuxfordevices.com/tutorials/linux/install-fedora-on-windows.
That was OK.

Then I tried to switch fedora to use systemd, by creating  `/etc/wsl.conf` as

```
[boot]
systemd=true
```

I guess I should install systemd pkg first,
because I got

```
PS C:\Users\xxxxx> wsl
Catastrophic failure
Error code: Wsl/Service/CreateInstance/E_UNEXPECTED
```

Now the question is `can I edit wsl.conf for not-booting VM` ?

Answer (score 3):

Mounting the vhdx image file on another distro made possible to edit the /etc/wsl.conf on faulty system.

**On Windows:**

```
wsl -d <working system> --mount --vhd <path to image>\<image name>.vhdx --bare
```

Example: wsl -d Ubuntu-20.04 --mount --vhd c:\wsl\vms\Ubuntu-22.04\Ubuntu-22.04.vhdx --bare

**Inside the working system:**

1. Mount the device on a mount point (Example: $ sudo mount /dev/sdc /mnt);

> Note: You can use lsblk to discover the new */dev/sd?*

2. Edit the <mount point>/etc/wsl.conf, removing the *[boot] systemd=true* part;
3. Umount and exit the system.

**Back on Windows, umount the image:**

```
wsl --unmount \\?\<path to image>\<image name>.vhdx
```

Example: wsl --unmount \\?\c:\wsl\vms\Ubuntu-22.04\Ubuntu-22.04.vhdx

Check if the former faulty system boot up.